# Creating Bot fighter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha, bots

Many sites I visited will display an image containing some random characters. I have to type the characters into the box before I can proceed. I assume this is to prevent some robot from flood the database with too many entries.

I have been asked by my management to do some similar. I write in asp.net with c#. Are there any tools out there to make this easier? I could probably write something from scratch. Although I’m not sure how I would create an image with random characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a "CAPTCHA" image. google it and there are a lot of samples for it. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CaptchaImage.aspx

Comment: I want to thank everyone. This answer was the most useful to me, so it is getting the green check.

Answer (score 11):

The thing you look for is called a CAPTCHA

You can use ReCaptcha:
http://www.google.com/recaptcha

it's a free and easy to use captcha service

Answer (score 0):

These are called CAPTCHA's. There are many existing pre-built solutions for installing them on your website.

Check out http://www.google.com/recaptcha for one of the more popular ones.